# Multiple search value using dropdown list in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Html Form:**

```
<form>
    <select name="country[]" id="country" multiple>
        <option value="any">any</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$country = $_REQUEST['country'];
if($country=="")
    $countrysql = "";
else
{
    if($country == "Any") $countrysql = "";
    else
    {
        $country = str_replace(",","','",$country);
        $countrysql = " and Country in ('$country')";
    }
}
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM register where $countrysql";
?>
```

I have created a form in PHP and I want to search multiple options. I already created table Register and a column Country. I am getting the result If I give single value. If I give multiple I am not getting the result. Please help.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Multiple errors are there in this code. Provide better explanation by giving examples

Comment: This is not complete code, just a syntax. I just want to know whether it is a correct syntax or not.

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL's `IN`? Example: `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN(1,2,3,4)"`. More [info here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: This is the statement where I used SQL IN                                    $countrysql = " and Country in ('$country')";

Comment: Let me know if there is any other method so that I can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You evaluate in `if($country == "Any")` the word **Any** is not equal to **any** in option `<option value="any">any</option>`

But I suggest this php code:

```
<?php
    $country="";
    $countryError="";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["country"])){
       $countryError = "Country is required"; 
    }else{
     $country = $_POST["country"];   
    }

    if($country == "Any") {
       $queryString = "SELECT * FROM register";  
    }else{  
         $queryString = "SELECT * FROM register where Country in ('$country')"; 

    }
// Print the SQL string:
    echo $queryString;
}

?>
```

The html tags:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <select name="country" id="country" multiple>
        <option value="Any">any</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>

    </select>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
 <span class="error"><?php echo $countryError;?></span>
```

Comment: I tried this method but when I select multiple values, the output result is single value. I selected India, UK and USA and got results only for USA.